# Sharing several git repos between computers

Tags: git, version-control

At any given time I'm working on several papers in LaTeX.  I like to keep my papers in git repos in order to use branching, be able to revert, etc. etc.  Part of the time I work on my computer at my office, and part of the time at home.

I have a directory containing several git repos (each for one paper, in its own subdirectory).  I'd like a good way to manage all of these repos across the computers.  Of course I could simply clone every repo on both computers and push/pull across a server, but then I have to clone every single repo by hand, create new directories on both computers every time I start a new project, etc.

Instead I could keep all the projects in the same repo, but I want to have separate branches going for each, and I need to be able to share certain projects with certain coauthors.  My current approach is to simply rsync everything when I go home at night, but then it's a nuisance if I forget to sync before I leave.

Question: what is the "right" way to handle this situation?

(other relevant info: I am running Linux and prefer a command-line approach.  No Dropbox allowed.)

Comment: Branches aren't designed for unrelated content, and Git doesn't support per-branch permissions (though certain server software might add this). I strongly recommend staying with per-project repositories.

Comment: That was my impression -- thanks for confirming!  Right now all the papers are in separate repos, and I'd like to keep it that way. What I want is an easy way to clone the whole set of repos at once, instead of one by one.

Answer (score 3):

You have at least three range of options:

a) **SSH**

This is the simplest way, because it only needs [Git](http://git-scm.com/) and [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell). You could have a central repository on one of your machines using ssh (which is one of the protocols git supports) and point all your "slave" repositories to this one. Check [this link](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) for more information.

This approach does not require Internet connection, only ssh access to the machines, Git does the rest of the magic.

b) **Publish repositories via HTTP on your own machine**

You can host your repository via HTTP on one of your Linux machines using [gitorious](http://gitorious.org/gitorious). The bad part is that you have to set up the configuration. Once it's done, you are all set!!

This approach does not require Internet connection assuming your machines are on the same or a reachable network.

c) **Hosting via Bitbucket or Github**

Assuming that your papers will be private repositories, I recommend using [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) (as it is free for private repositories). [Github](https://github.com/) is even better (IMHO), but for private repositories it's [not free](https://github.com/pricing).

Both Github and Bitbucket work via a HTTP or SSH connection to those websites, so they require having an Internet connection.

**Keeping repos synchronised:**

One of the ways to do this is using [hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/zh/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). This approach cab be combined with one of a) or b). Basically, after each push, you can run a script to sync the rest of the repositories, via rsync or any other approach.

Comment: Thanks!  I know how to share any single repository over SSH (though I haven't tried the others).  But I want a way to copy over the whole directory structure to a different computer (by cloning each repo into an identically named folder), without having to manually do this for every single repo on both computers.

Comment: I have added a section on the response that can help you: "Keeping repos synchronised"

Comment: Ah, that's an interesting way to do it!  So you'd recommend I continue to use my current setup with a single synced copy of each repo, rather than generate a separate repo (per paper) on each computer and push/pull between them?  I wasn't sure which would be better.

Comment: @Mark I recommend you to keep a repository per paper (it will be better for keeping the history, unless the papers are all related to a single line of "research") and a single machine who act as a "server": this machine will have on every paper repository a hook to update the other machines with the changes.

Comment: Will the other machines have a clone of the repo and changes move between them via push/pull to the server, or the other machines get changes by rsync of a single copy?

Comment: Whatever that looks like the fastest way for you: I think that for this case git pull will be faster than rsync, but both of them will work via hooks.

Comment: OK, thanks again!  I will accept this in a few hours unless somebody comes along with a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

If your question mainly about easy management of mutable set of repositories in common location, you can think about Git submodules or subtrees:

Parent directory (which holds all **real** repos) become empty "super-repository" with repositories as submodules|subtrees (but still part of superrepo for fetch|push|clone), adding|removing node is just a question of single command|editing relevant config-file